# Django передача переменных в скрипт js

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Много искал, не нашел ничего лучше, как передавать массив в скрипт js через

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    massages = {{ notification_messages|safe }};
</script>
```

Все прекрасно работало, в js была доступна переменная notification_messages, до тех пор, пока браузер не стал хешировать все что находится в этом теге `script`. Пробовал рандомно менять id элемента, задавать `<script type="text/cacheable"  data-hash={{rand}}>`, но браузер не хочет обновлять script. Я не понимаю почему он вообще хеширует html и не знаю что делать. Отключить хеш не вариант. Можно ли как-то по-другому передавать переменные js, или как заставить браузер не трогать этот `<script>`?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение, которое сработало для меня, использует скрытое поле ввода в шаблоне

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="variable" value="{{ variable }}">
```

Затем получаем значение в javascript таким образом:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("myVar").value;
```